# ZigZag Border (parent % height)

Tags: css, border

I am trying to use this example: http://dabblet.com/gist/3401493 which says to use this for the border:

```
.tophalf:after {
    content: " ";
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    bottom:-30px;
    height:30px;
    outline:1px solid red;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, white 75%) 0 50%,
                linear-gradient( 45deg, transparent 75%, white 75%) 0 50%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size:30px 30px, 30px 30px;
}
```

However, my top half has a percentage height of 50% so the border does not goto the bottom of the div.  How would I go about fixing this?

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to apply the zigzag border in an absolute way so it will stick to the bottom.

1. First we need an container so the div with class tophalf can adjust to height 50%
2. secondly we need to apply position:relative; to the tophalf class so the zigzag border will stick to the bottom
3. Now we can replace position:relative to position:absolute; in your code
4. Set the bottom:-30px to 0px

I set up an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rym6p/2/

The html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tophalf">
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
body{background:green;}
.container{height:480px;}
.tophalf{background:blue; height:50%; width:240px; position:relative;} 

.tophalf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 75%, white 75%) 0               50%, -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, white 75%) 0 50%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 30px 30px, 30px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

really liked this question and answer.

However, it handles zigzags facing down only.

I am adding here SCSS solutions for up/right/left/right directions.

Hope this will be useful for others.

```
@mixin zigzag_downward( $color ){
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, transparent 75%, $color 75%) 0 50%,
    linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, $color 75%) 0 50%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size:30px 30px, 30px 30px;
}

@mixin zigzag_upward( $color ){
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, $color 25%, transparent 25%) 0 50%,
  linear-gradient(-45deg, $color 25%, transparent 25%) 0 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size:30px 30px, 30px 30px;
}

@mixin zigzag_left( $color ){
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, transparent 75%, $color 75%) 0% 0,
    linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 75%, $color 75%) 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size:30px 30px, 30px 30px;
}

@mixin zigzag_right( $color ){
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, $color 25%, transparent 25%) 0% 0,
    linear-gradient(135deg, $color 25%, transparent 25%) 0% 0%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size:30px 30px, 30px 30px;
}
```

Here is a codepen example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HjJBF